# Why LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode Does not make any difference?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection, windbg

// Sample Program  ( Details https://alexatnet.com/articles/memory-leaks-in-net-applications/large-object-heap-fragmentation)

```
 class Program
{
private static List<byte[]> _arrays = new List<byte[]>();
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start allocations.");
    Console.ReadLine();
    var index = 0;
    var size = 8 * 1024 * 1024; // 8Mb
    var dsize = 7 * 1024 * 1024; // 7Mb
    while (true)
    {
        // Create object that allocated in the beginning of the heap segment:
        var local = new byte[dsize];
        // Next allocated object will be placed next to it:
        _arrays.Add(new byte[size]);
        // Destory first object:
        local = null;
        //System.Runtime.GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = System.Runtime.GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
        GC.Collect();
        //GC.Collect(2);
        // At this point heap segment has a free space of “dsize” bytes
        // at the beginning and object of “size” bytes after it:
        // [ ... free, ~7Mb ... ][ ....... 8Mb .......] - 16 Mb total

        // Increase the dynamic size so the next allocated object
        // does not fit in any free region:
        dsize += 100;
        index++;
        Console.WriteLine("Iteration {0}: press any key to continue.", index);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Both output are based on 10 iterations.

1. I disabled LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode Setting and try to get look at heap after 10 iteration. It look like following. Here you can see that free memory fragment of 7340078 , 7340174 so on.

> ```
> 0:006> !dumpheap 04401000
> Address       MT     Size
> 04401000 00ee2d38       10 Free
> 04401010 00ee2d38       14 Free
> 04401020 72eadc28     4708     
> 04402288 00ee2d38       14 Free
> 04402298 72eadc28      524     
> 044024a8 00ee2d38       14 Free
> 044024b8 72eadc28     4092     
> 044034b8 00ee2d38       14 Free
> 044034c8 72eadc28     8172     
> 044054b8 00ee2d38  7340078 Free
> 04b054e8 72eb2518  8388620     
> 05401000 00ee2d38  7340174 Free
> 05b01090 72eb2518  8388620     
> 06401000 00ee2d38  7340278 Free
> 06b010f8 72eb2518  8388620     
> 07401000 00ee2d38  7340374 Free
> 07b01158 72eb2518  8388620     
> 08651000 00ee2d38  7340478 Free
> 08d511c0 72eb2518  8388620     
> 09651000 00ee2d38  7340574 Free
> 09d51220 72eb2518  8388620     
> 0a651000 00ee2d38  7340678 Free
> 0ad51288 72eb2518  8388620     
> 0bae1000 00ee2d38  7340774 Free
> 0c1e12e8 72eb2518  8388620     
> 0cae1000 00ee2d38  7340878 Free
> 0d1e1350 72eb2518  8388620     
> 0dae1000 00ee2d38  7340974 Free
> 0e1e13b0 72eb2518  8388620     
>
> Statistics:
>       MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
> 72eadc28        4        17496 System.Object[]
> 00ee2d38       15     73405326      Free
> 72eb2518       10     83886200 System.Byte[]
> Total 29 objects
> ```

2. Now I enable LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode ( you have to make that line enable in code).

> ```
> 0:006> !dumpheap 031f1000
>  Address       MT     Size
> 031f1000 00652d98       10 Free
> 031f1010 00652d98       14 Free
> 031f1020 72eadc28     4708     
> 031f2288 00652d98       14 Free
> 031f2298 72eadc28      524     
> 031f24a8 00652d98       14 Free
> 031f24b8 72eadc28     4092     
> 031f34b8 00652d98       14 Free
> 031f34c8 72eadc28     8172     
> 031f54b8 00652d98       14 Free
> 031f54c8 72eb2518  8388620     
> 047d1000 00652d98       14 Free
> 047d1010 72eb2518  8388620     
> 05901000 00652d98       14 Free
> 05901010 72eb2518  8388620     
> 06b51000 00652d98       14 Free
> 06b51010 72eb2518  8388620     
> 07b51000 00652d98       14 Free
> 07b51010 72eb2518  8388620     
> 08b51000 00652d98       14 Free
> 08b51010 72eb2518  8388620     
> 09b51000 00652d98       14 Free
> 09b51010 72eb2518  8388620     
> 0afe1000 00652d98       14 Free
> 0afe1010 72eb2518  8388620     
> 0bfe1000 00652d98       14 Free
> 0bfe1010 72eb2518  8388620     
> 0cfe1000 00652d98       14 Free
> 0cfe1010 72eb2518  8388620     
>
> Statistics:
>       MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
> 00652d98       15          206      Free
> 72eadc28        4        17496 System.Object[]
> 72eb2518       10     83886200 System.Byte[]
> Total 29 objects
> ```

Now I have following confusion.

Test : 32Bit Application.

1. Even if we did set LOH Compaction setting why did still **14 Free** over there ? For what purpose it kept 14 Free over there ?
2. If you run this program in 115 or 116 iteration on 32 Bit application It will throw out of memory exception ? So why does setting of LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode does not make any difference ?

Comment: You are assuming that the LOH is one huge chunk of memory.  it is not, the CLR had to grow it incrementally, allocating chunks with VirtualAlloc() as you allocate these arrays.  These chunks are not contiguous in the address space, note the addresses and the space between them.  So there isn't any way that it can merge them, it did the best it could.  Compacting the LOH could be useful if it contains holes of > 85KB but less than the growth increment size.  Do target x64 if this is important to you, this is getting to be a very old-fashioned problem.

Comment: No. I knew it will max 2gb for 32 bit process. I want know largeobjectheapcompactionmode working in this case

Comment: Use Rohitab API monitor and watch the VirtualAlloc() and VirtualFree() calls